# Replace whole turbocharger or only the waste-gate actuator?

Tags: turbocharger, opel, astra, waste-gate

I have an Opel Astra H Caravan 2008 1.7 CDTI 81kW (type 0035/AHO). I started having some problems with the turbocharger. After reaching a certain velocity on the highway the car suddenly loses power and the yellow service led lights up. In my auto service they solved the problem by fixing the turbocharger's waste-gate actuator (moving it back and forth) - it was stuck. They also said, it could happen again and the real solution would be replacing the turbocharger. This problem happened twice this year, in both cases the service unstuck the actuator and then it worked for a while.

[image: Turbocharger waste-gate actuator]

Should I really replace the turbocharger? Would it be possible to change only the actuator (which is much cheaper)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on which part is sticking. If I've reconnoitered your turbo correctly, it has a built in wastegate. If it's the wastegate which is sticking and not the actuator, then you're wasting money by replacing the actuator (the turbo replacements I've seen for your engine come with a new actuator). You need to verify which part is at fault, otherwise you're just wasting money.

I don't really blame you for just wanting to replace the actuator, as it appears a new turbo for your engine is pretty expensive. Don't make it more expensive by replacing the wrong part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How to verify which part is sticking?

Comment: As a thought (as not quite sure), disconnect the actuator from the wastegate arm. Check the swing of the wastegate arm to see that it is operating correctly without sticking. On the actuator, you'll have to see how it operates. You'd need to apply vacuum to it and ensure it is operating correctly. Check to make sure it moves without any vacuum leakage from the diaphragm.

Answer (score 4):

This is an opinion question, so you may get varied answers. This is my opinion.

In my experience, I have found it is always best to start with the simple and work toward the difficult. In your case, I would start with the wastegate before going to the expense and difficulty of changing the turbo itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you can purchase just the wastegate actuator, I would do just that. It's bound to be vastly cheaper--if you can buy it separately. They are not difficult to replace--assuming you have room enough to replace just that. If you have to remove the turbocharger first, it adds to the labor and time but still you will likely come out ahead.

You can also inspect the turbocharger for shaft play and/or leaks to determine if it's nearing time to replace it.

And like Paulster2 mentioned, it may be the flap on the exhaust/turbine of the turbocharger that is sticking and not the actuator itself.